# Observer deleted not working when model deleted as relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have 2 models: Project > Planning
I have a PlanningObserver in which I want to delete folders from storage, when the Planning is deleted. If I delete a planning itself, it works without a problem.
However when I delete the project, which deletes the plannings, then the folder does not get deleted.

PlanningObserver:

```
public function deleted(Planning $planning)
    {
        $this->deleteDialuxData($planning);
    }

    private function deleteDialuxData(Planning $planning) {
        $directory_path = $planning->user_id . '/' . $planning->custom_planning_id . '/';
        Storage::disk('dialux')->deleteDirectory($directory_path);
    }
```

ProjectController:

```
public function destroy(Project $project)
    {
        if (auth()->user()->id !== $project->user_id) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Kein Zugriff'], 403);
        }

        $project->plannings()->delete();

        $project->delete();
        return response()->noContent();

    }
```

Any ideas what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

I misread the code. `$project->plannings()->delete()` doesn't trigger any model events. If you want to delete all plannings and still trigger events, you can do it like so: `$project->plannings()->get()->each->delete()`.

ORIGINAL:

You need to register your observer. You can register it on the `boot` method of `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider`.

```
/**
 * Register any events for your application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    User::observe(UserObserver::class);
}
```